# EBean enhancement maven

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, ebean

I'm trying to get Ebean working in my spring Kotlin project, but I keep getting this exception when I run my application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class com.sshmanager.server.database.entity.User is not enhanced?
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1556) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1423) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1333) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:748) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:369) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:197) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:124) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:35) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:109) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:70) ~[ebean-11.22.4.jar:na]
    at com.sshmanager.server.database.EbeanFactoryBean.getObject(EbeanFactoryBean.kt:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sshmanager.server.database.EbeanFactoryBean.getObject(EbeanFactoryBean.kt:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:171) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

I already added the `io.ebean.tile:enhancement` plugin.

I also tried `mvn ebean:init` command to add ebean.mf to control enhancement, but I get an exception when I run it:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] --- tiles-maven-plugin: Injecting 1 tiles as intermediary parent artifacts for com.sshmanager:server...
[INFO] Mixed 'com.sshmanager:server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' with tile 'io.ebean.tile:enhancement:5.6' as its new parent.
[INFO] Mixed 'io.ebean.tile:enhancement:5.6' with original parent 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.4.RELEASE' as its new top level parent.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- codegen-maven-plugin:4.2:init (default-cli) @ server ---
---------------------------------------------
EBEAN : INIT  - interactive ebean initialiser
---------------------------------------------


Commands:
  M - Manifest - add ebean.mf to control enhancement (recommended)
  P - Test properties - Add test-ebean.properties to configure Ebean when running tests (recommended)
  L - Logging - Add test logging entry to log SQL when running tests (recommended)
  G - Generate migrations - Add GenerateDbMigration for generating DB migration scripts (recommended)
  D - Docker - Add support for running tests against Docker containers (Postgres, ElasticSearch etc)
  F - Finders - generate finders
  T - Type safe query beans - manually generate them (rather than via APT/KAPT)
  Q - Quit
  Select an command: [M/P/L/G/D/F/T/Q] > M
Select a package that will contain the entity beans
  0 - Other
  1 - com.sshmanager.server.database.entity
select one of the options above
1
---- answer: com.sshmanager.server.database.entity
[ERROR] Error running detection on project
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring (String.java:1931)
    at io.ebean.codegen.Detection.diff (Detection.java:186)
    at io.ebean.codegen.Detection.getTopPackage (Detection.java:124)
    at io.ebean.codegen.InteractionHelp.questionTransactionalPackage (InteractionHelp.java:44)
    at io.ebean.codegen.DoAddManifest.run (DoAddManifest.java:21)
    at io.ebean.codegen.Interaction.executeManifest (Interaction.java:123)
    at io.ebean.codegen.Interaction.executeCommand (Interaction.java:48)
    at io.ebean.codegen.Interaction.run (Interaction.java:36)
    at io.ebean.codegen.InitMojo.execute (InitMojo.java:46)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.859 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-02T15:02:21+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/206M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can't find anyone else with this exception...

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I'm using the newest version of Ebean.

**EDIT**
I am using Intellij and just installed the Ebean enhancement plugin but it still doesn't work.. In the build messages I can see that my entities are enhanced but I still have the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class com.sshmanager.server.database.entity.User is not enhanced?
```

Comment: @JarekToro for some reason it started working, so not really...

Comment: I guess in meantime you upgraded to a new version which fixed it?

Comment: I've not used `mvn` before, but in `play` we add `ebean.default="models.*"` to the config file and it fixes this issue. So possibly you are missing some config

Comment: @Bsquare I forgot to mention one thing. It works in Intellij, I haven't tried it with mvn/gradle yet because my product is still in development.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation reference: https://ebean.io/docs/getting-started/maven

Note that you need
- the enhancement tile (which you have)
- src/main/resources/ebean.mf  (which looks like you where missing?)

Note that `mvn ebean:init` is deprecated and replaced by the cli tool.
Refer to https://ebean.io/docs/getting-started/cli-tool

Also note that there is a troubleshooting page for this: Refer to https://ebean.io/docs/trouble-shooting

Answer (score 0):

Check for two thing 
Below is present in pom

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>io.ebean</groupId>
            <artifactId>ebean-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>11.11.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>main</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformArgs>debug=1</transformArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And your bean has all the required annotation like
@Entity, @Table, and the POJO extends io.ebean.Model

Also you check this below link if you didn't get it right
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4kmglM48Vc

Answer (score 0):

if you used ebean 11.x , you can install Ebean ORM eclipse enhancement plugin see [ebean enhancement plugin](https://github.com/ebean-orm-tools/ebean-eclipse-enhancer)
right click in project-> select configure -> select Enable Ebean Enhancer 11.X